# injecting a variable into my library service

Tags: angular, angular-library, angular-injector

I'm creating a library in angular, which uses HttpClient and I need to inject the baseUrl to use.

this is what I have in the library:

```
//service 
export class ApiService {

constructor(
  private readonly httpClient: HttpClient,
  @Inject('baseUrl') private baseUrl: string) {
}

get<T>(resource: string,  options?: object): Observable<T> {
  return this.httpClient.get<T>(`${this.baseUrl}${resource}`, options);
}
}

// Module
@NgModule({

imports: [
  CommonModule
],
providers: [
  ApiService
]
})
export class NxServicesModule {

 public static forRoot(baseUrl: string): ModuleWithProviders<NxServicesModule> {

  return {
      ngModule: NxServicesModule,
      providers: [
        {
          provide: ApiService,
          useValue: baseUrl
        }
      ]
  };
 }
}
```

Then I try to use it in my application, this is my module1.module

```
@NgModule({
declarations: [
  MyComponent
],
imports: [
],
exports: [
],
providers: [
  ApiService.forRoot({baseUrl: environment.baseUrl})
]
})
```

It raises an error when compiling:

```
Property 'forRoot' does not exist on type 'typeof ApiService'.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `forRoot` is declared in your `NxServicesModule` not in your `ApiService`. Also you should pass a `string` not an object, or you should change the argument of the `forRoot` method accordingly.

---

**Note:** Doesn't your IDE catch these things? And the compiler should also log errors for these things I would say. Maybe you should check your configuration?

### UPDATE

Some clarification after your comment. You need to change as follows:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    MyComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    NxServicesModule.forRoot(environment.baseUrl)
  ]
})
```

Comment: I'm so sorry, but I'm not sure I'm undestanding what you mean with NxServicesModule, do you mean it should be  ModuleWithProviders<ApiService> ? it doesnt work either. Can you please give more information?

Comment: it works perfect, just one point the line with the NxServicesModule.forRoot should be in mports instead of providers

Comment: @cucuru Yeah, you're right, I simply missed it when I copied it from your question.